# Need to figure out how to parse GETDATE() to compare it against HHMMSS value in a table to find elapsed time

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, parsing

I need to find a way to create an alert that will alert me of the elapsed time of a non-sql batch job. The information on the batch job is recorded in the database.

I have a table named F986110 that records the submission time of these batch jobs. The date is recorded in the JCSBMDATE field as a six number value 1YYDDD, where YY = the last two digits of the current year and DDD is the current day numbered from Jan 1. For example, Feb 25, 2011 would be 111056. The time is recorded in the JCSBMTIME column in a military style hhmmss format, but no leading 0 for times before 10am. There is also a status column that indicates processing (P), waiting (W), and done (D).

My task is to send an alert out for all jobs that are in P or W status for longer than 15 minutes.  I've been banging my head against this for some time. I've found a lot of good stuff that is pointing me in the right direction but having to parse the system time, compare it to each record returned, and alerting on those (if any) that match is beyond my skills.

Comment: CAST/CONVERT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: Your answer uses CONVERT -- seems I understood the question just fine.

Comment: @OMG no offence but you might as well say use TSQL or use some SQL date functions. It is that broad.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: You're referring to a comment, not an answer.  You keep hounding me about nonsense, I will take offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert JCSBMDATE (1YYDDD) and JCSBMTIME to datetime

```
declare @t table (JCSBMDATE char(6),JCSBMTIME varchar(6))
insert @t select '111056', '104602'
insert @t select '199365', '81602'

select dateadd(d,
               right(JCSBMDATE,3)-1,
               convert(datetime,'01/01/' + substring(JCSBMDATE,2,2),3)) +
       convert(datetime, stuff(
                         stuff(JCSBMTIME,
                               len(JCSBMTIME)-3,0,':'),
                               len(JCSBMTIME),0,':'))
from @t
```

Reverse conversion which is more index friendly

```
select '1' +
       right(year(getdate()),2) +
       right(1000+datepart(dy, getdate()),3) as JCSBMDATE,
       right(1+replace(convert(char(8),getdate(),8),':',''),6) as JCSBMTIME
```

You can easily adjust `getdate()` with `dateadd(mi,-15,getdate())` to get JCSBMDATE and JCSBMTIME values 15 minutes ago.

Comment: +1 - OP should also know he can use a view instead of having to calculate this repetitively.  If the values don't change the view should hold the values without recalc.

Comment: @JNK: A [non-materialized] view won't change anything in that regard.

Comment: @JNK, @OMG Using the reverse conversion, a view won't be needed. But it would be useful to materialize an index by creating an index on a COMPUTED column for standard datetime.